# Formatting Markdown and CSS files using Prettier through ESLint?

Tags: css, markdown, eslint, prettier

Currently, I've got Prettier set up through ESLint using the following `.eslintrc.json`:

```
{
  "extends": ["react-app", "plugin:prettier/recommended"]
}
```

This works fine for linting and formatting JavaScript files.

However, when I'm trying to run ESLint (and thus Prettier) on Markdown and CSS files, errors like the following occur:

```
/Users/willem-aart/Code/foo/bar.md
  1:1  error  Parsing error: Unexpected character '#'

> 1 | ## foobar
    | ^

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

It seems that ESLint cannot handle the file. On the other hand, Prettier – when run standalone – handles the file as expected.

Is it possible to format files *other than JavaScript* using Prettier through ESLint? Or am I better off using Prettier standalone?

I guess Prettier can be applied to a broader range of file formats than ESLint is intended for.

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. The benefit would be that there would be a single runner & output of everything related to formatting / linting. Otherwise, prettylint is a nice tool.